# Android fragments using v7 appCompat library

Tags: android, android-fragments

I downloaded the fragmentbasics.zip from the [Android Training site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). At the bottom of the page (from provided link) there is a section stating *"If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend ActionBarActivity, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity"*. I am using the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in my project.

I did as the tutorial page says and updated 'MainActivity.java' to extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity, I am now getting the below errors...

1. The hierarchy of the type MainActivity is inconsistent
2. The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
}
```

Based on the tutorial I guess I am doing things correctly, any ideas why I would be getting these errors?

Steps to reproduce:

1. download the sample from provided link (top of post)
2. right click project -> build path -> add external arhchives
3. find your v7 appCompat support jar and click open
4. observe errors

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Iam running into it

Answer (score -1):

Try to update the android.support.v4

Comment: No clue what you mean by that. Can you please find the newly added steps to reproduce this error and see if that can help to give more details on how to fix?